# How to be multiple publishers on ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-server, arccatalog

I have and account named "sde" and "publisher" on my ArcGIS 10.5.1 geodatabase.

I have two account on ArcGIS Server named "siteadmin" and "publisher".

So I have published the REST services on Server using "sde" db user fom ArcMap. My MXD sources are using "sde" user informations. And ArcGIS server services data source uses "sde" user accounts.

When "publisher" user wants to publish his own MXD file from ArcMap, an error occured following:

```
data source must be registered with the server.
```

Because his db connection user informations are different.

In this stuation, will all publisher use "sde" user?

Comment: Never, never, *ever* load any map data using the `sde` login. This is often the first step toward completely trashing your database instance. It's also unwise to publish data as the owner. Instead you should use the *least privilege* model, with the data owned by an owner accout,  which has granted needed access to roles, which have been  granted to publisher login(s) which are used to actually use the data by the map service. The publisher login(s) are then registered with the server. The `sde` login should *never* be registered with ArcGIS Server.

Comment: @Vince thanks for informations, I am only one user of arcgis server manager. So I was new at arcgis server, so published using `sde`. What did you mean saying `trashing your database`?

Comment: One oops with a DELETE or DROP and the instance is toast.

Comment: In this stuation assume I have two users in database named "user1" and "user2" and when I "user1" publish the a service from arcmap, "user2" should be update service from his machine. But arcgis server site included databas conection with "user1" so user2 can not update the rest service from arcmap. How can I solve this problem in main question?

Comment: Database logins and ArcGIS Server publishers are very different things. It will take hours to write this anwser.